# Pandas to_csv leads to extra lines

Tags: pandas, dataframe

The data frame has 906133 rows, such as:

> > > df.shape

(906133, 24)

And I tried to save it as a csv file:

> > > df.to_csv('df.csv',encoding='utf-8-sig',index=False)

Then read it again;

> > > test_lines = pd.read_csv('df.csv')

However, it has now much more rows:

> > > test_lines.shape

(16512050, 24)

After some observation, the extra lines mainly contain a series of dots (...........) or commas (,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,). If I put a sep = '\t' for both saving and reading command, the number of extra lines decreased, but still existed.

Comment: Could you post a sample of how your data looks like. It seems you aren't reading the csv properly

Answer (score 1):

I got to a similar problem, however I was constructing the csv from scratch (not importing).

My blank lines disappeared after I used these parameters:

```
df.to_csv('df.csv', mode='w', encoding='utf-8', index=False, line_terminator='\n')
```

I blame the **line_terminator** to be be the culprit but the **index** parameter was responsible also for some extra separators. I hope this helps also on your side.
As @Vishnudev wrote we do not have your dataset so we cannot test. If you submit, we can confirm.